# Local host not working after changes in httpd.conf - apache

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

OSX Yosemite 10.10
2.4 apache

Error: After localhost in browser, I get below error:

`The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Following are the changes I've made:

*1* 
file httpd.conf

changed username to mine, it belongs to groups `_www` So group is unchanaged.

uncommented

LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

In
 etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf

*#LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so*

*#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf*

--

*ServerName localhost*

File **/etc/apache/users/myname.conf** has Directory pointing to:

*/Users/myname/Sites*

With

`Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks`
 `AllowOverride All`
`Order allow,deny`
`Allow from all`

**Points:**
- I've not edited *Directory* or *DocumentRoot* in httpd.conf
- I have info.php in /users/myname/Sites folder
- Am I running it incorrectly? 
Tried in browser as:

localhost, localhost/myname/Sites/info.php, localhost/info.php

Nothing worked.

`apachectl configtest`
`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist`
`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist`
`Syntax OK`

Restarted server every time I made changes.

`chmod 777 ~/Users/myAccount/Sites`

Please guide me here.

PS: I am fresh to apache, webserver, config file settings.

Comment: check error.log of apache, it will guide you.

Comment: I'm unable to deduce much from it. It mentions `warnings` which I get while `configtest`.

Comment: Can you add your error.log entries?

Comment: BTW, chmod 777 is not recommended. Don't forget to back it off to 775 or 755 once you get it debugged :)

Comment: @speeves Sure, will change rights. 
I managed to find the issue. I did 2-3 things:
- I changed rights.
- Was running incorrectly.
It should have been `localhost/~username/`
I didn't know `tilde` sign is important. 
- Added `index.html` in `Sites` folder. :)

Thank you.